# Existence of geometric tubular neighborhoods in Finsler spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, finsler-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator\Tub{Tub}$I have not found any reference among the well-known books about the existence of a geometric tubular neighborhood in the Finsler spaces. I am wondering if there exists such a neighborhood for any closed submanifold of a Fisnler Manifold $M$ (maybe with some extra hypothesis on $M$ ,like compactness ....).

FYI: by a geometric tubular neighborhood, of a pre-compact submanifold of a manifold $M$, I mean: $\Tub(P)_r:=\{\gamma(1)|\gamma:[0,1]\longrightarrow M $ is a minimizing geodesic with $\gamma'(0)\in\mathfrak{C}_{\gamma(0)}(P)\cap B(r)\}$. where $B(r)$ is the ball of radius $r$ and by $\mathfrak{C}_x$ we mean the subset of vectors that each one is orthogonal to $T_xP$ at the direction of itself.

Comment: What's your definition of a tubular neighborhood?

Comment: The [tubular neighborhood theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tubular+neighborhood+theorem) holds quite generally in the category of smooth manifolds. Unless you want special compatibility conditions with the Finsler structure, the result is the same.

Comment: In which case, Willie's answer applies. The definition does not depend on any metric or other geometric structure in addition to the manifold structure itself.

Comment: @WillieWong Notice that in Finsler spaces we always should be careful with the direction. It meansif a vector $v$ is orthogonal to a submanifold in some direction, $-v$ may not be orthogonal to that submanifold. So for a submanifold $L$ of $M$, the subset $\mathfrak{C}_x\subset T_xM$ that contains the vectors orthogonal to $L$ at point $x$, may not be a vector space (We say that a vector $v$ is orthogonal to $L$ if it is orthogonal at the direction of itelf.). As a result we may not have any decomposition as $T_xM=T_xL\bigoplus \mathfrak{C}_x$ and so any normal bundle.

Comment: @DeaneYang I am using the usual definition which is also given here en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubular_neighborhood 
or if it helps something equivalent which is:
A tubular neighborhood of a submanifold $L$ of $M$ is the set $\{\gamma(1)\ :\ \gamma$ is a geodesic whose initial velocity is orthogonal to $L$ at the direction of $\gamma\}$

Comment: The definition in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubular_neighborhood makes no reference to and does not need orthogonality. A submanifold in a Finsler manifold $M$ has a tubular neighborhood, because $M$ is a smooth manifold. The Finsler metric isn't needed at all.

If a manifold has a distance function defined on it, then you can define a tubular neighborhood as the set of all points within distance $\delta$ of the submanifold. That works for a Finsler manifold, because the Finsler metric defines a distance function.

Comment: @DeaneYang when a geodesic is minimizing the length from a submanifold to a point, it must be orthogonal to that submanifold. This is why we need to talk about the orthogonal spaces. 
Read your comment again, you are saying that the Finsler metric is not needed at all and then you are using the distance function associated to a Finsler norm! By the way, could you please give me the reference that you are using the definition of tubular neighborhood from.
Notice that once we want to talk about the tubular neighborhood, we need the normal bundles. What is the normal bundle here?

Comment: For the definition of the normal bundle (without any reference to a Riemannian or Finsler metric) of a submanifold, see the section titled "General Definition" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_bundle.

Comment: @DeaneYang How you want to find the quotient space then? You need a metric to find the appropriate direct sum of the tangent space at each point. So the normal bundle does depend on the metric.

Comment: Yes, this is confusing. The normal bundle itself is defined without the use of a metric, because given any vector bundle $E$ and a subbundle $K$, there is a naturally induced vector bundle $F$, where the fibers are $E_x/K_x$. This can be all done without any metric using local trivializations of $E$. This general construction can be applied to $E=T_*M$.

Comment: This discussion doesn't really belong here. It should be migrated to math.stackexchange.com . Briefly, to construct a tubular neighborhood of a submanifold, it suffces to construct one on a coordinate neighborhood of each point in the submanifold. That's straightforward using coordinates adapted to the submanifold. You can also construct it using a distance function. Any continuous one will do.

Comment: @DeaneYang For example look Theorem 5.1 of Differential and Riemannian Manifolds by Serge Lang. We do need the normal bundle to guarantee the existence of the tubular neighborhood.

Comment: The normal bundle always exists for a submanifold. See my explanation above.

Comment: Please move this question to math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Majid: your confusion may lie in the fact that: Given a vector space $V$ and a vector subspace $W$, it is always possible to form the quotient $U = V/W$. And you can always identify $V = U \oplus W$. The problem is that this latter identification is not unique. Once you have a metric you can canonically choose the decomposition such that $U \perp W$, but this orthogonality is not necessary in the construction of the quotient or the normal bundle.

Comment: The diffeomorphism in the tubular neighborhood theorem is by no means unique. In the Riemannian case we often prefer to use the one defined by the normal exponential map, but that is mostly to simplify computations.

Comment: Maybe I should put some comments on my question then. I believe that the tubular neighborhood that I am looking for is the same as given using the normal bundle. Anyway, I will correct the question based on these discussions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible approach that goes backwards, where we define the tubular neighborhood first and the normal bundle second.

Let $M$ be a Finsler manifold and $S \subset M$ a smooth submanifold. Given any $x \in M$, we can define the distance $d(x,S)$ from $x$ to $S$ to be the shortest length of curves from $x$ to $S$. We'll call a curve segment $S$-minimizing if one endpoint lies in $S$ and the length of the curve equals the distance from the other endpoint to $S$.

Then one can define a tubular neighborhood of $S$ of radius $r$ to be the set of all possible endpoints of $S$-minimizing geodesics. However, this is simply the set of all points within distance $r$ from $S$.

We can now define a subset $N_*S \subset T_*M$ with respect to the Finsler metric as follows: $v \in T_pM$ lies in $N_pS$ if there exists an $S$-minimizing curve starting at $p$ such that $v$ is tangent to the curve at $p$.

Using the existence and uniqueness of a geodesic with given starting point and velocity, we can define the exponential map $e: N_*S \rightarrow M$.. Moreover, this should show that $N_*S$ is in fact a vector bundle over $S$ and the exponential map defines a diffeomorphism from a neighborhood of the zero section of $N_*S$ onto a neighborhood of $S$ in $M$. In particular, given any precompact subset of $S$, there exists $r>0$ such that the exponential map is a diffeomorphism onto the tubular neighborhood of radius $r$ from its preimage.

Comment: As I already mentioned, $N_pS$ is not necessarily a vector space and so $N_* S$ is not a vector bundle. Moreover, the exponential map in the case of Finsler is not smooth at zero.

Comment: As far I know, the exponential map is not smooth only along $S$ itself, and this is due to the geodesics coming in on opposite directions not meeting at $S$ smoothly. It will, however, be $C^1$. That's also presumably why $N_*S$ is not a vector bundle. It's really a "ray" bundle, where there is scalar multiplication but not vector adition.

Comment: As you mentioned the exponential map is not a diffeomorphism in a neighborhood of the zero section and so we cannot accept this as an answer.